# Disable input field via service: Angular2

Tags: angular

I have a form with a text input field which I want to disable when the user makes an asynchronous call. The first and very basic approach is:

```
<input type="text" disabled="someBooleanVar" />
```

and set the boolean var to false. But since I'm making an async calls multiple times in the code, I don't want to write

```
this.someBooleanVar = false
```

multiple times. Instead, I have a service which contains a function and that function gets called every time an async call is made. So I'm trying to write a boolean var inside that service and toggle it inside the function of that service and hence do something like the following:

```
<input type="text" disabled="serviceObj.someBooleanVar" />
```

But this approach is not working. Can somebody point out whats going on here?

Comment: Have you tried to change `disabled="serviceObj.someBooleanVar"` to `[disabled]="serviceObj.someBooleanVar"`？

Comment: @awmleer, yes I tried that, didn't work.

Comment: Did you try `[disabled]="serviceObj.someBooleanVar"` and setting the service variable to `true`? The variable must be `true` to disable the control.

Comment: Yes I'm setting it to true inside the service function that I'm calling on every async call, @ConnorsFan

Comment: Did you assign the service to your component? In the constructor of your component, did you just do `constructor(serviceObj)`? Or did you assign it with `constructor(public serviceObj)`?

Comment: Show your component and your service code. It's hard to discern a good picture of what's going on from just the template excerpt. Also, be specific about how something doesn't work, including error messages. "It's not working" doesn't give us much info either. By the way, you didn't directly answer the first part of @ConnorsFan question.  To property bind, use the brackets: `[disabled]=` instead of `disabled=`

Comment: @BeetleJuice I believe the `[disabled]` portion of the question was answered after @awmleer asked it (first and second comments).

Comment: @FrankModica yep, thanks.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console when running your code?

Comment: @ConnorsFan, I don't see any errors in the console. BTW something interesting happened, when I replaced [disabled] with [readonly], it worked. Technically both of them are different attributes, but readonly serves the purpose in my case. Still I'm curious why [disabled] isn't working.

Comment: Do you get the same result with different browsers?

Comment: You could try with `[attr.disabled]=...`. Maybe setting the attribute will work better than setting the property.

Comment: @ConnorsFan, yes I tested it in Chrome, Firefox and Safari.

Answer (score 0):

A similar issue was reported on [GitHub](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11271) and it appears that setting the attribute worked when setting the property didn't. You could do this:

```
<input type="text" [attr.disabled]="serviceObj.someBooleanVar ? 'disabled' : null" />
```

Comment: just tried this approach, this disables the input text field regardless of the boolean value.

Comment: You can try with a string variable (`"true"` or `"false"`). I modified my answer to show one way of doing it.

Comment: no even the string values isn't working. But something def wrong, I inspected the element" <input _ngcontent-c3="" class="form-control input-lg ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" placeholder="Search the Catalog" type="text" ng-reflect-form="[object Object]" disabled="false"> ... clearly shows disabled property is false, still the input property is disabled

Comment: I modified my answer again. :-)

Comment: thanks, but that didn't work either. Maybe its a bug on Angular side?

Comment: One last try with `null` this time. Please note that the value is `null` and not `'null'`. The `disabled` attribute is probably activated for any string value; setting it to `null` could remove it. That solution worked for kekeh in the [GitHub discussion](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11271) mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

You can just try `BehaviorSubject`

Plnkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/ReasP8DWhzR6lCwjtmjO?p=preview

Service :

```
private status$ = new BehaviorSubject(true);

public getStatus$(){
  return this.status$.asObservable();
}

public setStatus$(status){
    this.status$.next(status);
}
```

Component :

```
this.status$ = _service.getStatus$();
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" [disabled]="status$ | async" />
```